# Getting Permission 'run.services.setIamPolicy' denied error on cloud build while deploying cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

Getting below error on cloud build while deploying a cloud function:

ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[Permission 'run.services.setIamPolicy' denied on resource 'projects/[ProjectID]/locations/us-central1/services/function1' (or resource may not exist).]

I have tried giving service account user role to cloud build service account, still the error persist.

Also, enabled services on cloud build but error is same.
[image: cloud build setting page]

Comment: Have you also tried [granting a role to the Cloud Build service agent](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account#service-agent-permissions)? Also what's the role granted for your Cloud Functions?

Comment: You have disabled services that should be enabled. Examples: Compute Engine, App Engine, Secret Manager, etc. For example, App Engine is used behind the scenes for many services. Do not disable services unless you know why. Enabled services do not cost money unless you use them. However, disabled service can cause things to break.

Comment: @Vaibhav, were you able to resolve this issue?